# Console I/O : printf & scanf not occurring in expected order

Tags: c, shell, io, stdin, console-input

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void eat() // clears stdin upto and including \n OR EOF
{
    int eat;while ((eat = getchar()) != '\n' && eat != EOF);
}

int main(){

    printf("\n COMMAND : "); char cmd[21]=""; scanf("%20s",cmd);

    if(strcmp(cmd,"shell")==0||strcmp(cmd,"sh")==0)
    {
        getchar(); // absorb whitespace char separating 'shell' and the command, say 'ls'
        while(1)
        {
            printf("\n sh >>> "); // print prompt
            char shellcmd[1024]=""; // str to store command
            scanf("%1023[^\n]",shellcmd); eat(); // take input of command and clear stdin

            if(strcmp("close",shellcmd)==0||strcmp("x",shellcmd)==0)
                break;
            else
                system(shellcmd);
        }
    }
}
```

In the code, some anomalous behavior is occurring which I'm unable to catch.

Upon entering `sh ls` and pressing `[ENTER]`, the expected response is:

1. 1st `scanf()` stored `sh` in `cmd[]` and leaves  `ls\n` in `stdin`.
2. `getchar()` takes up the   space.
3. `printf()` prints `\n sh >>>` to Terminal
4. second `scanf()` stores `ls` in `shellcmd[]`, leaves `\n` in stdin
5. `eat()` reads the `\n` from stdin, leaving it empty
6. `system("ls")` is executed

I.e. results should be like this:

```
 COMMAND : sh ls

 sh >>>
 file1 file 2 file3 ...

 sh >>> | (cursor)
```

**BUT**

What I get:

```
COMMAND : sh ls

file1 file2 file3 ...
 sh >>> 
 sh >>> |
```

Apparently, the 2nd `scanf()` and `shell()` are executing **before** `printf()` , or at least that's *my* assumption.

What's amiss?

*Compiled on Clang and GCC with `cc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and tested on bash on MacOS as well as Linux*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can find in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf):

> If a stream refers to a terminal (as stdout normally does) it is line buffered

So you might experience a delay in seeing the message printed by `printf` whenever it doesn't contain a newline. On the other end, the previos message is displayed as soon as the leading newline of the next `printf` is sent.

Solutions:

1. Add a newline at the end your message `printf("\n sh >>> \n");`
2. Force the current buffer to be displayed even in absence of a newline by calling [`flush()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) function (`fflush(stdout)`)
3. Change the current *stdout* buffering behavior with `setvbuf()` function

   ```
   setvbuf(stdout,NULL,_IONBF,0);
   ```

Comment: Oh, I see  0 0 ... so its *not* a fault with my program exactly :)

Comment: @user13863346 try it (I would start with option 2) and let me know if it works

Comment: Yup, this worked ... its fixed ! flush() works, and so does `'\n'` at the end of my format string.. I'm daunted by the 3rd so won't try it ;)

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Does C have its own man-pages or are the 'Linux man pages' the authoritative guide ?

Comment: @APJo C "man-pages" are actually the language standard document. For example here it is the description of the streams in stdio library: https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.2 and in following 7.21.3§3 you can find more or less the same definition I quoted about fully buffered/line buffered/unbuffered streams. I usually post descriptions from linux.die.net that IMHO is a reliable source (and it can provide more hints about the relationships among the APIs)

Comment: @user13863346 Just call `setvbuf(stdout,NULL,_IONBF,0);` before printing anything.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 that line of code was supposed to be in my answer as the code example of suggestion #3. Thanks to your comment I realized I forgot to add it

Comment: The fault is with the insanely unintuitive basic C console api…

Comment: @UnslanderMonica I was just about to comment that `setvbuf(stdout,NULL,_IONBF,0);` is extremely non-intuitive and also quite cumbersome 0_0